# Replace parameters in JSON with given Values from .csv

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I have a JSON-File where I want to replace several values with a placeholder.
So i made a .csv with the parameters to replace. line[0] (if existing) is the path in the file, line[1] the element, line[2] the placeholder.

```
journeys.legs.origin.properties.downloads;url;placeholder;
;url;placeholder;
download;url;placeholder;
;psFileName;placeholder;
;serverTime;placeholder;
;calcTime;placeholder;
```

now I defined the following functions, to get the file, read the csv and replace the stuff.

```
$storage = "D:\Service\test.json"
$parameters2replace = "D:\Service\parameters2replace.csv"


function Get-JSONProperty([object] $InputObject, [string] $Property) {
  $path = $Property -split '\.'
  $obj = $InputObject
  $path | %{ $obj = $obj.$_ }
  $obj
}

function setParameter(){
    foreach ($parameter in Get-Content $parameters2replace){
        $line=$parameter.split(";")        
        $path = $line[0]
        $elementName = $line[1]
        $newValue = $line[2]
        replaceElement $path $elementName $newValue       
    }        
}


function replaceElement($path, $elementName, $newValue){
    ForEach($JSONPath in Get-JSONProperty $JSON $path){
       if (!$line[0]){
            if($JSON.$elementName){
                $JSON.$elementName = $newValue
            }
        }
        else{
            if($JSON.$path.$elementName){
                echo $JSON.$path.$elementName
                $JSON.$path.$elementName = $newValue
            }
        }
    }
    $JSON | ConvertTo-Json -depth 32| set-content $storage 
}

    $JSON = Get-Content $storage -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
    setParameter
```

My problem now is, that the following if-argument won't work with the $path variable. If i put it in hardcoded it works just fine.

```
if($JSON.$path.$elementName)
```

I hope i could make everything clear, this was my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$JSON.$path` makes PowerShell look for a property with the literal name `'journeys.legs.origin.properties.downloads'`. You need to split the string into it's individual parts and iterate (or recurse) through the path:

```
function Get-JSONPropertyValue {
  param(
    $JSON,
    [string]$Path,
    [string]$Name
  )

  $object = $JSON
  foreach($propName in $Path.Split('.')){
    $object = $object.$propName
  }

  return $object.$Name
}

function Set-JSONPropertyValue
{
  param(
    $JSON,
    [string]$Path,
    [string]$Name,
    $Value
  )

  $object = $JSON
  foreach($propName in $Path.Split('.')){
    $object = $object.$propName
  }

  $object.$Name = $Value
}
```

Now you can do:

```
if($value = Get-JSONPropertyValue $JSON -Path $path -Name $elementName){
    echo "Old value: $value"
    Set-JSONPropertyValue $JSON -Path $path -Name $elementName -Value $newValue
}
```